# Implementing scrollify in website

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-scrollify

I've trying to implement [jQuery Scrollify](https://github.com/lukehaas/Scrollify) plugin into my website. However this plugin assume that my structure of the website is only with `sections` but is not. What I mean is that the structure of the website is

```
<body>
<div class="mobilenav">
    ....
</div>
<header id="header">
    ....
</div>
   <section class="section section1"> Section 1 </section>
   <section class="section section2"> Section 2 </section>
   <section class="section section3"> Section 3 </section>
   <section class="section section4"> Section 4 </section>
   <section class="section section5"> Section 5 </section>
<div class="footer">
   ....
</div>
</body>
```

Here is how I implement it

```
$(function() {
 $(".section").css({"height":$(window).height()});
  $.scrollify({
    section:".section"
  });


  $(".scroll").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.scrollify("move",$(this).attr("href"));
  });
});
```

So the problem is when site is loaded and when I scroll it shows only the `<section>`.. it doesn't show `<header>`, `<footer>` and anything else which is not wrapped in section class. Is it possible to avoid this?

Comment: If you haven't taken a look at [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) I would highly recommend it to you. Much more options and compatible with old browsers and touch devices. Also dealing with kinetic scrolling and providing updates every month. And if you need scroll bar, just use `scrollBar:true` as [in here](http://www.alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrollBar.html).

Comment: I'll add that having your own code to make each section the height of the page could conflict with Scrollifys function to do the same thing. So I'd turn off setHeights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it works on `<section>` it can be hard to avoid this situation.

Maybe just wrap your `<div>` into `<section>` like this :

```
<section>
 <div>
 </div>
</section>
```

You will have everything working good, and also you can manage all options described [here](https://github.com/lukehaas/Scrollify) in section 'Options'

Comment: Well I don't know why I didn't think about just to wrap that div into <section> tag. Silly me.. Thank's this do the trick.

Comment: Any idea why `scrollSpeed: 1100` doesn't work.. I saw it in `Option` section but doesn't matter what value I put it didn't work?

Comment: Maybe `scrollSpeed: 1100` is not working because you need to define `easing` ? I dont know, its just a blind shoot :)

Answer (score 5):

Scrollify sections are defined in the initialisation of Scrollify. They are user defined so they can be anything you want.

```
$.scrollify({
    section:"this-is-a-css-selector"
});
```

Regarding your header and footer, you could use interstitialSection for those.
This would make your initialisation look like this:

```
$.scrollify({
    section:".section",
    interstitialSection:"#header,.footer"
});
```

That way Scrollify will still scroll to them but won't manipulate their height.